# \sqrt is not working

Tags: symbols, mnsymbol

Why sqrt is not working? (I don't want to remove packages)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{letters}{46}{largesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{letters}{47}{largesymbols}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ \qty(\frac{2}{3})+\sqrt{x} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have chosen mnsymbol which uses a non standard font encoding and redefined all commands to use that encoding, then you have switched the largesymbols font back to cmex so will break all commands using that font except for the two you redefine afterwards.

Comment: So is there a way to fix this? @David Carlisle

Comment: don't load mnsymbol or don't use cmex  what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I just want to learn, to see if we can fix these types of problems without removing the packages @DavidCarlisle

Comment: your question is "I have painted an apple orange, but I wanted a green apple" the answer is "eat an apple or eat an orange". I honestly have no idea how to answer this. You have two sets of conflicting definitions and asking for a fix that does not involve removing the conflict, and without saying what you were trying to do.

Comment: You can obviously revert sqrt just as you have reverted () but that will leave all other large symbols broken. You could revert every definition made by mnsymbol but not loading it is simpler than loading it then undoing all its definitions.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your ideas. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of the `largesymbols` font overrides the one made by `MnSymbols`. However even if the `MnSymbol` font `MnSymbolE` is supposed to be OMX encoded, it actually isn't.

In particular, the radicals are in a very different position than in compliant OMX encoded fonts. In `MnSymbol.sty` we find

```
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{largesymbols}{'272}{largesymbols}{'272}
```

whereas LaTeX has, by default,

```
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{symbols}{"70}{largesymbols}{"70}
```

In decimal `'272` is 186, whereas `"70` is 112. In slot `'272` the `cmex` fonts have nothing.

If you want to substitute some of the choices made by `MnSymbol`, you should use a different name, say

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmexlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmexlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{letters}{46}{cmexlargesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{letters}{47}{cmexlargesymbols}{1}
```

However, my opinion is that `MnSymbol` should only be used if the main document font is Minion. You *might* import select symbols from it, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the declaration of the `\sqrtsign` :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{letters}{46}{largesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{letters}{47}{largesymbols}{1}
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{largesymbols}{"70}{largesymbols}{"70}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ \qty(\frac{2}{3})+\sqrt{x} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for thank you @Frédéric Loyer

Comment: yes sure but that will still leave every other command using laregsymbol broken, so after you have re-instated every such command the question I was trying to ask the OP is why load a package and then revert all its definitions rather than not load the package?